# How to use a block parameter in a ruby splat?

Tags: ruby

Using `Ruby 2.0.0p247`

Say I have a `def`:

```
def foo (a, b, &block):
    bar[[a, b]] = block
end
```

How do I code the block parameter if I use `splat` parameters with this function?

e.g.

```
params = [:a, [:2], { |m| m.oo }] # syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'

foo(*params) # how do I make this work?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass it like this:

```
params = [:a, [:2]]
block = lambda { |m| m.oo }

foo(*params, &block)
```

A few things here:

- The block doesn't have to be in it's own variable, but that's more convenient than array chopping
- You have to define a block with lambda if it is not syntactically attached to a method invocation

If you *absolutely* need to put it in one array, (I think) you can do this:

```
params = [:a, [:2], lambda { |m| m.oo }]
foo(*(params[0..-1]), &(params.last))
```

If you may or may not have a block, it's easiest to change foo:

```
def foo (a, b, block = nil):
    bar[[a, b]] = block
end
```

By removing the & you can no longer call foo like this:

```
foo(a,b) {|m| m.oo}
```

But you can use the form you initialy showed in your question:

```
params = [:a, [:2], lambda { |m| m.oo }]
foo(*params)
```

Or like this:

```
foo(:a, [:2], lambda { |m| m.oo })
```

If you don't provide a block, it will default to nil.

Comment: So the `lambda` certainly removed the syntax error. But I still want to include the block in the `splat`, but it gives me a `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)` error.  Is there a way to include the block in the `splat` or is this the only way?

Comment: @Derek: Not without some fancy array cutting. See edit.

Comment: what about in the case I might or might not have a block, e.g. `params.length` could be 2 or 3, but if it had a block, it would be 3 and the block would be the last item.

Comment: just exploring options, so there's no way to keep the `&block` and have the optional block?

Comment: @Derek: No. Ampersand arguments in Ruby are special cases.